# How to configure Share Point 2010 on windows 7 with windows authentication

Tags: windows, sharepoint-2010, installation

I have already install `sql server 2008 r2` which is login by using windows authentication.

And then after install `Sharepoint2010` foundation on my `Windows7 Ultimate` OS.

Now Next step is `SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard`.  Click on next button i reach to **Connect to server farm** where is select Create new server farm and click to Next.
[image]

Then It Popup with below screen,
[image]

I have problem here is that it require Database access account with UserName and Password and UserName in form `DOMAIN\User` , but i dont have User Name with domain,then i create login user for sql server and it have name like `SharePointUser` with Password. There is no domain name.

I tried to enter user Name like `Aamir-PC\SharePointUser`, but gives error like `User Name is invalid. The Account must have valid domain account`. Even i tried username like  `SharePointUser` but same error again.

I search a lot but i did not find any solution for above problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL server installed on the same machine then **Did you try to create a stand alone system instead of Server farm?** I have installed Sharepoint 2010 foundation in my Windows 7 OS but as a standalone farm.

Comment: Yes, i was install on  stand alone farm

Comment: The username SharePointUser is the same user available in your system as login account? If No, then use your account for the windows login which you use to login in to your Windows 7 PC .. A name and password you entered at that login screen in your windows